# How to log query for single table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.2

Have simple insert with returning id

```
INSERT INTO "public"."mytbl"  ("col1",  "col2" , "col3" , "col4",  "col5") 
values  ('test',  'test' ,  null ,  'test',  null) RETURNING id;
```

want log execution time for only this query. How to do it ? I dont want log all querys ,only this one

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line interface `psql`, you can simply enter

```
\timing
```

and you'll get the duration of each statement after it has been executed.

If you want to log the duration to the PostgreSQL log file, you can do that by setting the parameter `log_min_duration_statement = 0`.
The problem is that this parameter can only be set by the superuser, and you probably want to run the statement as a different user.

One way to enable a normal user to log statement duration is to use a `SECURITY DEFINER` function that is owned by a superuser and sets the parameter for the duration of the current transaction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logduration() RETURNS void AS
  'SET LOCAL log_min_duration_statement=0'
   LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER;

REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION logduration() FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION logduration() TO laurenz;
```

Then user `laurenz` can do the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT logduration();
INSERT INTO "public"."mytbl" ...
COMMIT;
```

Your log will contain only the duration of the `INSERT` command (well, also the duration of the funxtion call, but that shouldn't be a problem).